# Dynamically choose which #define to reference

Tags: c

I am writing an HTTP 1.0 downloader and using these #define replacements to format the query:

```
#define GET_FORMAT "GET %s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: getter\r\n\r\n"
#define HEAD_FORMAT "HEAD %s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: getter\r\n\r\n"
#define GET_FORMAT_RANGE "GET %s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nRange: %s\r\nUser-Agent: getter\r\n\r\n"
#define HEAD_FORMAT_RANGE "HEAD %s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nRange: %s\r\nUser-Agent: getter\r\n\r\n"
```

Im using something like this currently to replace the '%s' parts of the query string. I feel it could be more graceful:

```
char* query_string_formatter(char* page, char* host, int get){ 
    switch(get) {
        case 0:
        //HEAD
        {
            char* query = malloc(strlen(host) + strlen(page) + 1 + HEAD_FORMAT_LEN);
            if (page[0] == '/') {
                sprintf(query,HEAD_FORMAT, "", page, host);
            } else { 
                sprintf(query, HEAD_FORMAT, "/", page, host);
            }
            return query;
        }
        default: 
        //GET
        {
            char* query = malloc(strlen(host) + strlen(page) + 1 + GET_FORMAT_LEN);
            if (page[0] == '/') {
                sprintf(query,GET_FORMAT, "", page, host);
            } else { 
                sprintf(query, GET_FORMAT, "/", page, host);
            }
            return query;
        }
    }

}
```

But id love to replace it with something more graceful kind of like this:

```
...

sprintf(query, format, "",page,host);
```

Where format is either GET or HEAD, instead of having several nested if statements and repetitious code

Comment: Use plain (const) variables rather than macros. Those macros gain you nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent code repetition you can use a variable to memorize the format before

```
char* query_string_formatter(char* page, char* host, int get){
    char* query = malloc(strlen(host) + strlen(page) + 1 + HEAD_FORMAT_LEN);
    char *format;
    if (get)
        format = GET_FORMAT;
    else
        format = HEAD_FORMAT;
    if (page[0] == '/') 
        sprintf(query, format, "", page, host);
    else
        sprintf(query, format, "/", page, host);
    return query;
}
```

or even shorter but less readable :

```
char* query_string_formatter(char* page, char* host, int get){
    char* query = malloc(strlen(host) + strlen(page) + 1 + HEAD_FORMAT_LEN);
    sprintf(query, get ? GET_FORMAT : HEAD_FORMAT, page[0] == '/' ? "" : "/", page, host);
    return query;
}
```

Also: be sure that HEAD_FORMAT_LEN includes the '\0' ending, or add more 1 in `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd eliminate the macros entirely, and do something like

```
const char *format_string[] = {"GET %s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: getter\r\n\r\n",
                               "HEAD %s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: getter\r\n\r\n"};

char* query_string_formatter(const char* page, const char* host, int get)
{ 
    if (get != 0) get = 1;
    char* query = malloc(strlen(host) + strlen(page) + 1 + strlen(format[get]);
    sprintf(query, format[get], (page[0] == '/' ? "" : "/"), page, host);
    return query;
}
```

Optionally, the definition `format_string` in the above can be placed within the function `query_string_formatter()`.   Leaving it outside the function, at file scope, allows the array to be used by multiple functions in the same source file.

You didn't specify but I've assumed that - in your code - `HEAD_FORMAT_LEN` and `GET_FORMAT_LEN` can be replaced by `strlen(HEAD_LEN)` and `strlen(GET_LEN)` respectively.   That's more or less consistent with your usage   [in fact, using `strlen()` probably over-allocates slightly using `malloc()` but that's actually better than under-allocating - you want the buffer length to be *at least* the length of what is being copied to it].

You can probably rationalise even more, since the only difference between the two format strings is the usage of substrings `"GET"` and `"HEAD"` at the beginning.

You haven't shown any example of how your macros `GET_FORMAT_RANGE` and `HEAD_FORMAT_RANGE` are being used, but - if they are being used in a similar way in your code - they can be eliminated in a similar way.